# How do I use Hebrew characters with Entity Framework and SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, hebrew

I have a web service that takes XML, parses it to create EF objects, then persists those objects to the database (via the EF context).

This all works fine with normal English characters, but now someone wants to post Hebrew, but when he does, the value in the database is just ????.

The database column uses `nvarchar()`, and if I execute the following SQL in SSMS, it works just fine...

```
update customers 
set Salutation = N'אבגד' 
where LgID = 3 and VcID = 1

select * 
from Customers 
where LgID = 3 and VcID = 1
```

I can see the Hebrew correctly.

I have checked the data coming into the web service, and the value in the EF entity's property is correct, but when EF persists it to the database, it converts it to ????.

Anyone able to tell me what I need to do to allow Hebrew (as well as English) to be persisted? Thanks.

Comment: are you using an appropriate `SqlConnection`?

Comment: make sure that the IsUnicode facet is set to true in both conceptual and store models for the given property/column.

Comment: Please show us your EF data model and your DbContext class. Also how did you verify that the persion is getting ????. If you use SSMS to view the inserted row the same way you did your example you get questionmarks there too?

Comment: OK, turned out that the database was set up correctly, but I had forgotten to update the EF model to reflect the changes (ie changing varchar to nvarchar). Once I updated the model, it worked fine. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd better post this as a separate answer instead of a comment, in case anyone else comes looking for it.

Turned out that the database was set up correctly, but I had forgotten to update the EF model to reflect the changes (ie changing varchar to nvarchar). Once I updated the model, it worked fine.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in two days or your question will keep auto promoting to the front page as a question with no accepted answer for the next few months.